# PHP - Negate sign in string (timezone)

Tags: php

I'm using timezone in format `+0100` but now I need to change sign of it so:
`+0100` should be `-0100`
`-0300` should be `+0300`

And finally it'll be `DateTimeZone` object.

Any ideas how can I do this except `if` + `str_replace`?

This is what I have currently

```
$tzOffset = '-0100'; // Getting from request

if (substr($tzOffset, 0, 1) === '+') {
    $tzOffset = str_replace('+', '-', $tzOffset);
} else {
    $tzOffset = str_replace('-', '+', $tzOffset);
}

$timezone = new DateTimeZone($tzOffset);

// rest ...
```

Comment: Sounds to me like a XY-problem... what is the real issue? Why do you have to negate?

Comment: @B001ᛦ Like in question - I'm getting timezone offset in `+XXYY` format but I need to negate it to `-XXYY` or `-XXYY` into `+XXYY`

Comment: Show your code so far you've done.

Comment: @unclexo Added.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this (instead of `if` construct):

```
$tzOffset[0] = $tzOffset[0] === '-' ? '+' : '-';
```